# Python xmlutils, formatting xml to csv conversion

Tags: python, xml, export-to-csv

I am converting a generated xml file to a csv file using xmlutils. However, the nodes that I tagged in the xml file sometimes have an extra child node which messes up the formatting of the converted csv file.

For instance,

```
<issue>
  <name>project1</name>
  <key>733</key>
</issue>
<issue>
  <name>project2</name>
  <key>123</key>
  <debt>233</debt>
</issue>
```

I tagged "issue" and the xml file was converted to a csv. However, once I opened the csv file, the formatting is wrong. Since there was an extra "debt" node in the second issue element, the columns for the second were shifted.

For instance,

`name      key
project1   733
project2   123 233`

How can I tell xmlutil to generate a new column "debt"?

Also, if xmlutils cannot do the job, can you recommend me a program that is better suited?

Comment: I do not know of xmlutils, but you might try writing a program to parse the xml file and write into a csv file.

Comment: I thought about doing that. Honestly, there aren't many xml to csv converters, for python anyway.

Comment: have a look at lxml package. it has a pretty useful xml parser.